# While Loop Only Inserting Last Record

Tags: php, mysql

I have a while loop that displays checkboxes if a row meets the criteria.  It is within a form which I would like to submit and perform an insert.  This is the code for the loop:

```
<form action'' method='post'>

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM b_tasks_report WHERE TASK_ID=$taskid GROUP BY WEEK_ID");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='noborder'><input type='checkbox' name='invoicename[]' value='$invoicename - Week " . $row['WEEK_ID'] . "'>Week " . $row['WEEK_ID'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'></form>
```

This currently returns three checkboxes each labelled week 1, week 2 and week 3.  The issue I'm having is that when I submit the form and perform the insert then it only inserts the last row.  Here is my insert:

```
$sql="INSERT into b_sale_order (LID,PERSON_TYPE_ID,PAYED,CANCELED,STATUS_ID,DATE_STATUS,EMP_STATUS_ID,PRICE_DELIVERY,ALLOW_DELIVERY,DEDUCTED,MARKED,RESERVED,PRICE,CURRENCY,DISCOUNT_VALUE,USER_ID,PAY_SYSTEM_ID,DATE_INSERT,DATE_UPDATE,TAX_VALUE,SUM_PAID,RECOUNT_FLAG,UPDATED_1C,ORDER_TOPIC,RESPONSIBLE_ID,DATE_BILL)
VALUES
('s1','1','N','N','A','$_POST[insertdate]','1','0.00','N','N','N','Y','0.00','GBP','0.00','1','1','$_POST[insertdate]','$_POST[insertdate]','0.00','0.00','Y','N','$_POST[invoicename]','1','$_POST[insertdate]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
```

I use the insertdate post item a number of times.  I have tried adding the following to the name of the form field:

```
insertdate[]
```

And then including above the insert a:

```
foreach($_POST['insertdate'] as
```

But I can't get it to work.  Is it because I'm using the same post item a number of times for different fields? Should I add a hidden ID field for it to look at instead?

All in all I just want it to add 1-3 new rows depending on how many checkboxes are ticked.

Your help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all indexes $_POST variables in the insert statement should have quotes, try this

```
$names= $_POST['invoicenames']
foreach($names as $invoicename){
$sql="INSERT into b_sale_order (LID,PERSON_TYPE_ID,PAYED,CANCELED,STATUS_ID,DATE_STATUS,EMP_STATUS_ID,PRICE_DELIVERY,ALLOW_DELIVERY,DEDUCTED,MARKED,RESERVED,PRICE,CURRENCY,DISCOUNT_VALUE,USER_ID,PAY_SYSTEM_ID,DATE_INSERT,DATE_UPDATE,TAX_VALUE,SUM_PAID,RECOUNT_FLAG,UPDATED_1C,ORDER_TOPIC,RESPONSIBLE_ID,DATE_BILL)
VALUES
('s1','1','N','N','A','".$_POST['insertdate']."','1','0.00','N','N','N','Y','0.00','GBP','0.00','1','1','".$_POST['insertdate']."','".$_POST['insertdate']."','0.00','0.00','Y','N','".$invoicename."','1','".$_POST['insertdate']."')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything.  Just runs through as normal but nothing added.  Also needs a ; after the ['invoicenames'] I think...

Comment: Sorry fixed it, you had put ['invoicenames'] when it should be ['invoicename'].. Thanks for your help!

Comment: please mark it as **the answer** if this has solved your question, it will leave it out of the unanswered list